# Does ROS run on Windows?

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Considering that 90% of desktops are (still) Windows-based, are there plans on making at least some parts of ROS run on that OS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9066/does-ros-run-on-windows?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Update

It is possible to install and use ROS Lunar on Windows 10 thanks to WSL:
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

This is the best way to use ROS on Windows right now, though it is not perfect.

---

Efforts are underway to bring ROS to Windows.  There is already the [custom port done by REC](http://www.servicerobotics.eu/index.php?id=37) and there should (soon) be mingw compatibility coming from an external contributor.  We are working on a longer-term overhaul of the build system to make Windows compatibility possible.  It's a large enough effort that we can't make any promises as to when, but we think there's a large enough community now to make this finally happen.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-12-30**:
Any progress on this?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-08-07**:
@Pablo Iñigo Blasco yes: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-07**:
I believe it's important to recognise that ROSonWSL is not the same as having a native Win32/64 ROS. WSL does not have the same level of access to Windows resources, so 'driver' components wanting to access hw (usb, gpus for gpgpu fi) will not work (easily).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I am aware, not really.  :(

There's been some work getting some parts of RosPy to run a long time ago, and possibly some limited Cygwin success.

Here are some threads from ros-users that discuss this:

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Need-Help-Installing-ROS-in-Cygwin-on-Windows-td880700.html

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/RViz-on-Windows-td1021082.html

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rospy-in-windows-td217019.html

This does not mean, however, that Windows systems are entirely useless.  We show our Windows users how to use Putty to SSH into the linux computers on our robots and use the command line tools.  While they do not get RVIZ or other graphical tools, it still allows them to launch code, echo topics, etc.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5